# Partial derivative of squared Euclidean distance

Tags: derivatives, euclidean-geometry, partial-derivative

I have a hard time getting the partial derivative of this function
\begin{equation}
  d(\theta, \textbf{x}_i) = \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^{n_v} \vert\vert f(\textbf{x}_i^+) - f(\textbf{x}_j^+)\vert\vert^2_2 - \vert\vert f(\textbf{x}_i^+) - f(\textbf{x}^-)\vert\vert^2_2 
\end{equation}
and define $\phi_i^+ = \vert\vert f(\textbf{x}_i^+) - f(\textbf{x}_j^+)\vert\vert^2_2$ and $\phi_i^- = \vert\vert f(\textbf{x}_i^+) - f(\textbf{x}^-)\vert\vert^2_2$ to simplify the equation.

So, i would like to find 
$\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_i^+} d(\theta, x_i)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_i^-} d(\theta, x_i)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

I know that the partial derivative of the euclidean distance for 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} \vert\vert x - x_j\vert\vert = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N} (x - x_j)_k}{\vert\vert x-x_j\vert\vert}
\end{equation}

but how can I get for a squared euclidean distance.
Thank you

Comment: Do you know about a chain rule?

Comment: @MajaBlumenstein I know about the chain rule, just don't know how it can help here. Any suggestions?